# My Dockerize go application does not work. Error: /bin/sh: ./crawler: not found

Tags: docker, go

I wrote a program in golang to parse some sites. It worked correctly. Then I dockerized this program and tried to run it. Now it displays the following error:

> / bin / sh: ./crawler: not found

There is my Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.16-buster AS build

WORKDIR /github.com/Hudayberdyyev/crawler
COPY . .

RUN go mod download

RUN GOOS=linux go build -o crawler cmd/main.go

FROM alpine:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /github.com/Hudayberdyyev/crawler/crawler /crawler

CMD ./crawler
```

How can I find the cause of the problem. My operating system linux-server.20.04

Comment: I solve this problem. the error appears because in alpine when building the application, the CGO_ENABLED variable must equal zero. RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -o crawler cmd/main.go

Answer (score 0):

`alpine:latest` is a small Linux docker image - as such it is missing some core `glibc` libraries needed when building a Go program with CGO_ENABLED=1 (the default go build mode). `alpine` uses [musl libc](https://www.alpinelinux.org/about/)).

Setting `CGO_ENABLED=0` fixes this for some app builds - if they have no CGO requirements. Since that works here, you can want to avail of the `scratch` docker image to create a tiny image (`~11MB`):

```
FROM scratch

WORKDIR /

COPY --from=build /github.com/Hudayberdyyev/crawler/crawler /crawler

CMD ["/crawler"]
```

Note the last `CMD` line change is important - from the [docker CMD docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd):

> CMD ["executable","param1","param2"] (exec form, this is the preferred
> form)

as:

```
CMD ./crawler
```

will attempt to use `/bin/sh` the shell interpreter - which is not available in the bare-bones `scratch` image.